# User Provisioning Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, connected-apps

Has anybody created User Provisioning Flow for Connected Apps? There are no documentation related to it.

Can you anyone tell me what is the procedure or Plugin Link?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the working demo here.

[Summer '15: User Provisioning for Connected Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCgy9ywYzuY)

Comment: I have seen this already but when the Visual Flow Comes into picture then it is problem. There is no info how to create UserProvisoning Flow